# Magento 2.1.9 - System.log: "Attempt to load value of nonexistent EAV attribute '237' for entity type 'Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface'"

Tags: magento-2.1, log

The message "Attempt to load value of nonexistent EAV attribute '237' for entity type '`Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface`'" appears every time I load a product that has the custom attribute with **Id= 237**. It is happening in storefront and in backend.

**Preconditions**

- Magento 2.1.9
- Eshop with 1 storeview.

**Steps to reproduce**

- Create a custom attribute, dropdown with values 'disabled', 'enabled'
  and code=promot1.
- Insert it in all attribute sets.
- Go to a product in backend and make the promot1='enabled'.

**Expected result**

- In Catalog the product to appear with promot1=enabled.
- In product edit page the promot1 dropdown to have the value
  'enabled'.

**Actual result**

- In Catalog the product appears with promot1=enabled.
- In product edit page the promot1 dropdown has NO value.
- In system log I have the message: "Attempt to load value of
  nonexistent EAV attribute '237' for entity type
  '`Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface`'"
- The same message if I try to load the product in frontend.

Any suggestion why it is happening?.

Comment: I try to reproduce the issue on a clean installation on a new development server. Everything works properly and as expected. Is there any suggestion why it is happening on my production server?

Comment: I compared the tables between the two databases. I specify that the development server is working properly, while the production does not. I found differences only in the `tables catalog_product_index_eav_idx` and `catalog_product_index_eav_tmp`.

Do anyone know what exactly is the table `catalog_product_index_eav_idx` and how could this difference be corrected?

Comment: Finally I solved the problem by making a new installation on my production server. Apparently something went wrong in the previous installation.

Comment: can you tell please any other solution because i got same error when  i deleted some custom attribute from using code as well as manually from backend after this i got this error in log/system.xml